# How to estimate the memory usage for Random Forest algorithm?

Tags: r, random-forest, ram, r-caret

I am trying to fit a Random Forest model with `caret`. My training data weight 129MB and I'm computing this on Google Cloud with 8 cores and 52GB RAM. The code I'm using is below:

```
library(caret)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(3, outfile = '')
registerDoParallel(cl)
model <- train(x = as.matrix(X_train),
               y = y_train,
               method = 'rf', 
               verbose = TRUE,
               trControl = trainControl(method = 'oob',
                                        verboseIter = TRUE,
                                        allowParallel = TRUE),
               tuneGrid = expand.grid(mtry = c(2:10, 12, 14, 16, 20)),
               num.tree = 100,
               metric = 'Accuracy',
               performance = 1)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Despite having 8 cores, any try to use more than 3 cores in `makeCluster` results in the following error:

> Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection

So I thought maybe there is a problem with memory allocation and tried with only 3 cores. After few hours of training when I was expecting to have a result the only thing I got, to my amazement, was the following error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.9 Gb

Still, my google cloud instance has 52GB memory so I decided to check how much out of it is currently free.

```
as.numeric(system("awk '/MemFree/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo", intern=TRUE))
```

> [1] 5606656

Which is above 47GB. So assuming that 2GB couldn't be allocated in the end of training it seems that above 45GB was employed by training random forest. I know that my training dataset is bootstrapped 100 times to grow a random forest, so 100 copies of training data weight around 13GB. At the same time my total RAM is divided to 3 clusters, what gives me 39GB. It should leave me with around 6GB, but it apparently doesn't. Still, this is assuming that no memory is released after building separates trees and I doubt this is a case.

Therefore, my questions are:

1. Are my approximate calculations even ok?
2. What may cause my errors?
3. **How can I estimate how much RAM I need to train a model with my training data?**

Comment: Not an answer, but instead of using method `rf`, I would use method `ranger`. This will call the ranger package instead of the randomForest pacacke. ranger runs in parallel by itself and is more memory friendly. Since you have a cluster, you might look into the [h2o](https://www.h2o.ai/) package.

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/benchmarking-random-forest-implementations/ this might be useful.

Comment: One strategy could be to start with a "smaller" model and estimate its memory usage via the `mark` function from the `bench` package.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot correctly estimate the size of the random forest model, because the size of those decision trees is something that varies with the specific resample of data - i.e. the trees are built dynamically with stopping criteria that depends on the data distribution.